# Como faço pra ele aparecer na mesma pasta do arquivo que cria ele?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite3

Eu crio esse banco de dados em python3 mas ele surge em uma pasta anterior

```
import sqlite3

nome_banco = 'banco_escola.db'

banco = sqlite3.connect(nome_banco)
```

Answer (score 1):

Caso queira criar um arquivo em um diretório específico, basta passar um caminho absoluto para o arquivo ser criado.

Segue um exemplo:

```
import sqlite3
nome_banco = '/Users/nomeusuario/database.db'
banco = sqlite3.connect(nome_banco)
```

Desta forma o arquivo com nome `database.db` será criado no caminho absoluto desejado, neste caso será criado em: `/Users/nomeusuario/`